# function with optional arguments

Tags: macros

I have used TeX for some time, but never really 'coded' with it; please bear with me ;-)

I'm currently writing something that involves a lot of different norms and I want to write a macro / function that eases up the TeX-ing.

I declared the standard macro

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}
```

Now instead of defining one macro for each norm I use

```
\newcommand{\norms}[2]{\norm{#1}_{W^{1,p}}}
\newcommand{\normds}[2]{\norm{#1}_{W^{1,p}(#2)}}
\newcommand{\normmds}[3]{\norm{#1}_{W^{1,#2}(#3)}}
\newcommand{\normnms}[3]{\norm{#1}_{W^{#2,#3}}}
\newcommand{\normnmds}[4]{\norm{#1}_{W^{#2,#3}(#4)}}
```

(where `s` signifies the space, ie. the `W` in the subscript,
`d` stands for domain so I mean `$s(d)$`, `n` stands for the first exponent in the subscript like `$s^{n,m}(d)$`)

I would like to have something like this:

```
\norm [n,m,d,s]{}
```

and now putting arguments:

```
\norm [1,p,\Omega,s]{u}
```

to yield `\norm {u}_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}`

or

```
\norm [n=1,m=p,d=\Omega,s=W]{u}
```

to yield `\norm {u}_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}`

I hope my question makes sense, if not, let me know!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since the only way to differentiate `mds` from `nms` (both have 3 arguments) is to force explicit use of the commas (or else the `n=`, `m=` style), is it your intent that a plain `\norm` invocation would be `\norm[,,,]{}`?  That is to say, it would be helpful for us to see how you envision the invocation style for each of the 6 variations.

Comment: I am asking you to explicitly provide us a sample invocation that you would like have to produce the `\normmds` style, the `\normnms` style, etc.

Comment: im not sure i fully understand your question!

for the plain norm ill just use the ordinary macro `\norm` defined above (with some renaming of course), so NO i guess.

Comment: aha i see, so i don't know if its possible, but id like to have `\normmds{u} W {p} {\Omega}` as `\norm[p,\Omega,W] {u}` or if thats not possible as `\norm[m=p,d=\Omega,s=W] {u}`

Comment: But how do I know that `\norm[p,\Omega,W] {u}` doesn't imply `\norm[n=p,m=\Omega,s=W] {u}`?  They both have 3 arguments...

Comment: yeah, thats a good point, so i guess it's only possible with th `=` signs?

Comment: Anyway, you should take alook at the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` command and its siblings in the `mathtools` documentation  (§ 3.6, pp 25–29) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres now what i had in mind! finally solved it thank you all guys!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\ks{w}
\def\kc{c}
\def\kh{h}
\def\km{m}


\usepackage{kvoptions}


\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=snorm, prefix=snorm@}
\DeclareStringOption{n}
\DeclareStringOption{m}
\DeclareStringOption{d}
\DeclareStringOption{s}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\snorm}[2][]{%
\begingroup
\kvsetkeys{snorm}{#1}%
\left \lVert #2\right \rVert
\ifnum0\ifx\snorm@m\@empty\else1\fi
       \ifx\snorm@n\@empty\else1\fi
       \ifx\snorm@d\@empty\else1\fi
       \ifx\snorm@s\@empty\else1\fi
       >0 %            
% sob   
      \ifx \snorm@s\ks %
        _{W^{%
            \ifx\norm@n\@empty 1\else\norm@n\fi,%
            \ifx\norm@m\@empty p\else\norm@m\fi
            } %
          \ifx\snorm@d\@empty %
          \else %
          (\snorm@d)%
          \fi %\ifx\snorm@d\@empty
          } %_{W^{     
       \fi %\ifx \snorm@s\ks
% cam    
      \ifx \snorm@s\kc %
        _{\mathcal L^{%
          \ifx\norm@n\@empty p\else\norm@n\fi,%
          \ifx\norm@m\@empty \lambda \else\norm@m\fi
          } %
          \ifx\snorm@d\@empty %
          \else %
          (\snorm@d)%
          \fi %\ifx\snorm@d\@empty
          } %_{\mathcal L^{ 
       \fi %\ifx \snorm@s\kc  
% hol
        \ifx\snorm@s \kh %
          _{C
            \ifnum0\ifx\snorm@m\@empty\else1\fi %
                \ifx\snorm@n\@empty\else1\fi =0 ^0 %
                \else %
                  \ifx\snorm@n\@empty %
                  ^{\snorm@m} %
                  \else %
                  ^{\snorm@n, \ifx\snorm@m\@empty \alpha\else\snorm@m\fi}%
                  \fi %
                \fi %\ifnum
            \ifx\snorm@d\@empty %
            \else %
            (\snorm@d)%
            \fi %\ifx\snorm@d\@empty
            } %_{C
        \fi % \ifx\snorm@s \kh
% mor
      \ifx \snorm@s\km 
        _{L^{%
            \ifx\norm@n\@empty 2\else\norm@n\fi,%
            \ifx\norm@m\@empty \mu \else\norm@m\fi
            } %    
          \ifx\snorm@d\@empty
          \else
          (\snorm@d)%
          \fi %\ifx\snorm@d\@empty
          } %_{L^{
       \fi %\ifx \snorm@s\km
    \fi %ifnum
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother 


\begin{document}
\def\test#1\\{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$ \\%
}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \test\snorm{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=1,s=w]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=1,s=h]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=2,s=h]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[d=\Omega,s=h]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[m=\alpha,s=h]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=n,s=m]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[m=p,s=c]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[m=m,s=c]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=n, m=m,s=w]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[s=c,d=\Omega]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=1, m=p, d=\Omega, s=c]{u}\\
  \test\snorm[n=n, m=m, d=d, s=m]{u}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A key-value approach with keys `n`, `m`, `d`, `s`. If one of them is set, then
the subscript appears. Then, default values are used for `n` (`1`), `m` (`p`) and `s` (`W`) if the key is not given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=norm, prefix=norm@}
\DeclareStringOption{n}
\DeclareStringOption{m}
\DeclareStringOption{d}
\DeclareStringOption{s}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\norm}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \kvsetkeys{norm}{#1}%
    \left\lVert#2\right\rVert
    \ifnum0\ifx\norm@m\@empty\else1\fi
           \ifx\norm@n\@empty\else1\fi
           \ifx\norm@d\@empty\else1\fi
           \ifx\norm@s\@empty\else1\fi
           >0 %
      _{%
        \ifx\norm@s\@empty W\else\norm@s\fi
        ^{%
          \ifx\norm@n\@empty 1\else\norm@n\fi,%
          \ifx\norm@m\@empty p\else\norm@m\fi
        }%
        \ifx\norm@d\@empty
        \else
          (\norm@d)%
        \fi
      }%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\test#1\\{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$ \\%
}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \test\norm{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=1]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n]{u}\\
  \test\norm[m=p]{u}\\
  \test\norm[m=m]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n, m=m]{u}\\
  \test\norm[d=\Omega]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=1, m=p, d=\Omega, s=W]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n, m=m, d=d, s=s]{u}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- The `\DeclareStringOption{foo}` defines macro `\norm@foo`. It is `\@empty`, if the key is not used in the optional argument.
- `\kvsetkeys{norm}{#1}` (also `\setkeys` can be used) is called inside a group to preserve the initial settings of the parameter macros `\norm@...`.
- I tried to get a useful algorithm and the default values from the definitions of the commands `\norms` and friends.

Comment: merci monsieur!

Comment: how would i make sense out of something like ` \ifx \norm@s m \mathcal L \fi`?

is this the right command to compare a key? or do i have to use `\if \norm@s = W` or `\ifx \norm@s @W`

Comment: @cesareborgia Define a command: `\def\norm@param{m}` and compare: `\ifx\norm@s\norm@param ... s has value m ... \else ... otherwise ... \fi`

Answer (score 3):

A `listofitems` approach to obtain the key values.  Thanks to Heiko for the test tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\newcommand{\normplain}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}
\newcommand\norm[2][\relax]{\normplain{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\normaux{#1}\fi}
\newcommand\normaux[1]{%
  \def\nnormdata{1}% DEFAULT
  \def\mnormdata{p}% DEFAULT
  \def\dnormdata{\relax}% DEFAULT
  \def\snormdata{W}% DEFAULT
  \setsepchar{,/=}%
  \readlist*\normdata{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\normdata[]{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname\normdata[\xcnt,1]normdata\endcsname{\normdata[\xcnt,2]}%
  }%
  _{\snormdata^{\nnormdata,\mnormdata}\expandafter\ifx\dnormdata\relax\else(\dnormdata)\fi}
}
\begin{document}
\def\test#1\\{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$ \\%
}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \test\norm{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=1]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n]{u}\\
  \test\norm[m=p]{u}\\
  \test\norm[m=m]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n, m=m]{u}\\
  \test\norm[d=\Omega]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=1, m=p, d=\Omega, s=W]{u}\\
  \test\norm[n=n, m=m, d=d, s=s]{u}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A flexible key-value interface, also with choice of size (avoid automatic `\left` and `right`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\norm}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { cesareborgia/norm } { #1 }
  \cesareborgia_norm:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { cesareborgia/norm }
 {
  s .tl_set:N = \l_cesareborgia_norm_spc_tl,
  n .tl_set:N = \l_cesareborgia_norm_exp_tl,
  d .tl_set:N = \l_cesareborgia_norm_dom_tl,
  m .tl_set:N = \l_cesareborgia_norm_mlt_tl,
  size .tl_set:N = \l_cesareborgia_norm_size_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cesareborgia_norm:n
 {
  \__cesareborgia_norm_lsize:V \l_cesareborgia_norm_size_tl
  #1
  \__cesareborgia_norm_rsize:V \l_cesareborgia_norm_size_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_cesareborgia_norm_spc_tl
   {
    \sb
     {
      \l_cesareborgia_norm_spc_tl
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_cesareborgia_norm_exp_tl
       {
        \sp
         {
          \l_cesareborgia_norm_exp_tl
          \tl_if_empty:NF \l_cesareborgia_norm_mlt_tl
           {
            ,\l_cesareborgia_norm_mlt_tl
           }
         }
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_cesareborgia_norm_dom_tl
         {
          (\l_cesareborgia_norm_dom_tl)
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cesareborgia_norm_lsize:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {*}{\left}
    {}{}
   }
   { \use:c { #1l } }
  \|
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__cesareborgia_norm_lsize:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cesareborgia_norm_rsize:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {*}{\right}
    {}{}
   }
   { \use:c { #1r } }
  \|
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__cesareborgia_norm_rsize:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 \norm[n=1,m=p,d=\Omega,s=W]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,m=p,d=\Omega,s=W,size=Big]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,m=p,d=\Omega,s=W,size=*]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\\
 \norm[n=1,m=p,s=W]{u}+
 \norm[size=big,n=1,m=p,s=W]{u}+
 \norm[size=*,n=1,m=p,s=W]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\\
 \norm[n=1,s=W]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,s=W,size=bigg]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,s=W,size=*]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\\
 \norm[n=1,s=W,d=\Omega]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,s=W,d=\Omega,size=Bigg]{u}+
 \norm[n=1,s=W,d=\Omega,size=*]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\\
 \norm[s=W]{u}+
 \norm[s=W,size=big]{u}+
 \norm[s=W,size=*]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\\
 \norm{u}+
 \norm[size=Bigg]{u}+
 \norm[size=*]{\dfrac{u}{2}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]